# How to set property of a view in layout XML file in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

For example, I am using `android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip` and I want to call its `setTabIndicatorColor` with my choice of color. How to do it in layout XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best thing you can do is to consult the documentation. For `PagerTabStrip` it is [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerTabStrip.html).

There's a Summary section where you can check all XML attributes defined for that class. In this case, you can see that there are only attributes inherited from `ViewGroup` and `View`. None of them sets the tab indicator color.

This means that you need to set it in the code.

Let's look at the example where there is an attribute, e.g. orientation for [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html). There's a entry for `android:orientation` attribute which tells you exactly how to set it in XML.